# Symfony Crawler for a button that invokes ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, web-scraping

[Here](http://daraz.pk/phones/samsung/) I need to click $('button-see-more') which triggers an ajax call and loads more stuff on the page. I'm trying with

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('See More Products')->link();
$crawler = $client->click($link);
```

But that ofcourse won't work because it doesn't have any anchor tag.
This is the HTML, the button is actually a  element, I want to simulate a click on it

```
<div class="paging">
        <div class="mtl">
            <div class="button-see-more txtCenter" data-current-page="1" data-total-pages="3" data-txt-seemore="See More Products" data-txt-loading="Loading  More Items for Phones">
                <span class="i-loader hidden"></span>
                <span class="text">See More Products</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With crawler you can't detect a link from javascript,
but if you have already an ajax link, you can simulate your request by this method

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/foo/', array(), array(), array(
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
));
```

Comment: Also, if you want to test that the request does the desired action, you could also use Selenium with Behat/Mink or PHPUnit here.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs/blob/master/Tests/CasperTest.php

Comment: @abdallah I can see the URL being requested from developer console but the site is using CSRF tokens so when I use that URL again it simply takes me to home page

Comment: @abdallah After simulating the Ajax button click and after the ajax call returns 200 OK response code, how does the data returned by ajax request is updated in the already loaded $crawler?